# Using a Proxy Model when accessing foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I have two related Django models.  One of the models does expensive calculations in its `__init__` which I can't move elsewhere without unacceptable cost/risk.

It turns out these expensive calculations aren't needed in all contexts, so I introduced a proxy model that circumvents them.  They are needed more often than not, though, so it's not practical to make the expensive one into the proxy.

So, my code basically looks like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
    do_some_really_expensive_things()

class LightweightPerson(Person):
  class Meta:
    proxy = True

  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kw)

class PersonFact(models.Model):
  fact = models.TextField()
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

This works well -- most of my code queries on `Person`.  And in the few places where the code doesn't need the really expensive things, it queries on `LightweightPerson` instead, and performs better.

However, some of my code starts from `PersonFact` instances and accesses the related `person` for each `PersonFact`.  This code doesn't need the really expensive person calculations, and the performance hit from those expensive calculations is unacceptable.  So I'd like to be able to instantiate a `LightweightPerson` instead of a `Person` in this context.

The approach I came up with was to add a second `ForeignKey` that references the proxy class, and uses the same database column:

```
class PersonFact(models.Model):
  fact = models.TextField()
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column="person_id")
  lightweight_person = models.ForeignKey(
     LightweightPerson, db_column="person_id", 
     related_name="lightweight_personfact_set")
```

So now when I need the performance boost, my code can do things like this:

```
facts = PersonFact.objects.select_related(
             "lightweight_person").all()
for fact in facts:
  do_something_with(fact.lightweight_person)
```

And this works great!  Until I try to save a new `PersonFact`:

```
>>> fact = PersonFact(fact="I like cheese", person=some_guy_i_know)
>>> fact.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
DatabaseError: column "person_id" specified more than once
```

:-(

Is there any way to do this without a big scary refactoring of the code that's currently in `Person.__init__`?  Ideally I'd either be able to just signal "when accessing `person_fact.person` right now, please instantiate a `LightweightPerson` instead of a `Person`" in my calling code.  Or, alternatively, I'd like to be able to declare a "proxy related field" on `PersonFact` that shadows the same database column, but Django's internals know to only interact once with the database column.

Comment: I had a similar discussion in #django in IRC and basically they told me what I'm doing is considered a bug.  It's kind of frustrating when sometimes this is the only viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've come up with so far is to do something scary on the related model's `__init__`:

```
class PersonFact(models.Model):
  fact = models.TextField()
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column="person_id")
  lightweight_person = models.ForeignKey(
     LightweightPerson, db_column="person_id", 
     related_name="lightweight_personfact_set")

def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
    index = None
    for i, field in enumerate(self._meta.local_fields):
        if field.name == 'lightweight_person':
            index = i
            break
    if index is not None:
        self._meta.local_fields.pop(index)
```

This apparently hides the existence of that field from the object manager for updates and inserts, so the "column specified more than once" error doesn't occur; and the field still gets populated when I select existing data.

This seems to work, but it's pretty scary -- I have no idea if it will have side effects in other parts of my code.

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems to be safe enough .. my code hasn't exploded yet.